# GetListItems not returning items in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, caml

We are querying SharePoint 2013 webservice method - GetListItems to fetch list of items in a list but it is returning 0 items. The strange thing is **same piece of code was working for SharePoint 2010** as it used to return files list in a specified sharepoint list, however since upgrade to SharePoint 2013, it is returning 0 items without even throwing any exception.

Following are the parameters being passed to GetListItems method.

```
<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>Accounts</listName>
<query>
<Query xmlns="">
<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" /><Value Type="Text">foldertoread</Value></Contains></Where>
</Query></query>
<viewFields><ViewFields xmlns="" /></viewFields>
<rowLimit>50</rowLimit>
<queryOptions>
<QueryOptions xmlns=""><Folder>foldertoread</Folder></QueryOptions>
</queryOptions>
</GetListItems>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks a subtle change has been made in SharePoint2013 in the way it perceives  tag. Instead of mentioning folder name, we had to mention **complete folder path** for it to work.

Modified parameter list which worked:

```
<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>Accounts</listName>
<query>
<Query xmlns="">
<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" /><Value Type="Text">foldertoread</Value></Contains></Where>
</Query></query>
<viewFields><ViewFields xmlns="" /></viewFields>
<rowLimit>50</rowLimit>
<queryOptions>
<QueryOptions xmlns=""><Folder>Accounts/foldertoread</Folder></QueryOptions>
</queryOptions>
</GetListItems>
```